# Does anything prevent a website from filling the user's hard drive using IndexedDB?

Tags: security, web, storage, indexeddb

I have tested IndexedDB for storing large amounts of data in a web application lately. Based on my testing in various browsers on various devices and operating systems, it is very easy to store several gigabytes of data without the user even knowing about it or giving permissions. So that made me think, what prevents a random website you visit from "filling" your hard drive with nonsense?

There might be some storage limit, but it seems possible to use a significant part of the available storage capacity on many devices. The user could of course clear this data manually in some way, but I imagine that in most cases, the user won't be aware of what has happened and won't even know where to look. They will just notice that some percentage of their available storage has disappeared (if even that) and think it is caused by an OS update or something else they can't control. On e.g. mobile devices it is possible to see that the browser app is the one taking up a lot of storage space, but to then find what specific web app has caused this seems tricky. As far as my research goes most browsers don't give a simple overview of what websites have used IndexedDB so that you can easily clear the ones using the most storage. Am I missing something here, or could it be that a lot of devices are partially filled with a lot of IndexedDB data from a dubious website which was visited once?

I guess there won't be any real reason for any website to do this, as it seems hard to use this as part of any malicious attack, but I guess there are some people who would create such websites just to be annoying. Or it might even be caused by a bug in the webapp, making it e.g. insert some data over and over again.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about programming, it might be better on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I agree, this probably belongs on some other site. I do not know of the best place for it.